# Object entity to CSV serialization / conversion

Tags: c#, .net

How can I write all values (properties) into an csv formated string in C#?
e.g.:

```
class Person(string firstName, string lastName, int_age);
Person person = new Person("Kevin","Kline",33);
```

now I want a string **"Kevin;Kline;33"**

In other words I want to serialize an object into CSV

Comment: Your question needs far more background and examples of data/code to avoid being a candidate for closure.

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried?

Comment: @nonnb: you can post this as an answer, it's helpful.

Comment: Also, this is perhaps a minor nitpick, but the comma-separated value format uses commas to separate the values. You seem to be using semicolons.

Answer (score 17):

Have a look at [Josh Close's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68499/josh-close) excellent [CSVHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) library

```
var person = new Person("Kevin","Kline",33);
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter("file.csv")))
{
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ';';
    csv.WriteRecord(person);
}
```

Output:

```
Kevin;Kline;33
```

Comment: Is it possible to use CSVHelper, without the saving file.csv part? I don't want to write the file in the Hd, I intend to send the file as a response to the web user.

Comment: Best part is that it is availiable for .Net Core

Answer (score 9):

By using reflection you can retrieve the property infos from an object

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prp in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) {
   if (prp.CanRead) {
      object value = prp.GetValue(obj, null);
      string s = value == null ? "" : value.ToString();
      string name = prp.Name;
      ...
   }
}
```

The `GetProperties` method has an overload accepting `BindingFlags` through which you can determine which kind of property you need, like private/public instance/static.

You can combine them like this

```
var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | 
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                    BindingFlags.Instance);
```

---

Applied to your problem you could write

```
List<Person> people = ...;
Type type = typeof(Person);
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
var sb = new StringBuilder();

// First line contains field names
foreach (PropertyInfo prp in properties) {
   if (prp.CanRead) {
      sb.Append(prp.Name).Append(';');
   }
}
sb.Length--; // Remove last ";"
sb.AppendLine();

foreach (Person person in people) {
    foreach (PropertyInfo prp in properties) {
       if (prp.CanRead) {
          sb.Append(prp.GetValue(person, null)).Append(';');
       }
    }
    sb.Length--; // Remove last ";"
    sb.AppendLine();
}

File.AppendAllText("C:\Data\Persons.csv", sb.ToString());
```

It is also a good idea to enclose strings in double quotes and to escape doubles quotes they contain by doubling them.

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this:

```
...
        PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        string CSVRow = "";
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            CSVRow = CSVRow + pi.GetValue(obj, null) + ";";
        }
        CSVRow.Remove(CSVRow.Length - 1, 1);
...
```

Comment: ... but would also need to implement quoting / escaping rules.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) is good for this, I've not used it in anger myself though

Comment: It is good.  Too bad it doesn't work for .Net Core though :/  CSVHelper does!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public string ToCsv()
{
    return string.Join(";", new string[]{
        _firstName,
        _lastName,
        _age.ToString()
    }.Select(str=>Escape(str)));
}
```

Or, using reflection,

```
public static string ToCsv(this object obj)
{
    return string.Join(";",
        this.GetType().GetProperties().Select(pi=>
            Escape(pi.GetValue(this, null).ToString())
        ));
}
```

Where Escape is an appropriate escaping function.

Answer (score 0):

One possible implementation for you, that read complex objects (deep object serialization), like array of objects with properties that are array of objects, and saves o a string formatted like CSV file:

```
private string ToCsv(string separator, IEnumerable<object> objectList)
{
    StringBuilder csvData = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var obj in objectList)
    {
        csvData.AppendLine(ToCsvFields(separator, obj));
    }
    return csvData.ToString();
}

private string ToCsvFields(string separator, object obj)
{
    var fields = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

    if (obj is string)
    {
        line.Append(obj as string);
        return line.ToString();
    }

    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        var value = field.GetValue(obj);
        var fieldType = field.GetValue(obj).GetType();

        if (line.Length > 0)
        {
            line.Append(separator);
        }
        if (value == null)
        {
            line.Append("NULL");
        }
        if (value is string)
        {
            line.Append(value as string);
        }
        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(fieldType))
        {
            var objectList = value as IEnumerable;
            StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in objectList)
            {
                if (row.Length > 0)
                {
                    row.Append(separator);
                }
                row.Append(ToCsvFields(separator, item));
            }
            line.Append(row.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            line.Append(value.ToString());
        }
    }
    return line.ToString();
}
```